# Очистка памяти ,выделенной под двумерный динамический массив

Tags: c++, массивы

Можно ли очищать память таким образом?

```
delete[]a;
```

Или всё же так будет правильнее?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            delete[]a[i];
        delete a;
```

Comment: Зависит от того, как вы ее выделяли... Но в любом случае, раз это массив - `delete a;` - неверно.

Comment: `a = new int*[n];
  for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
 a[i] = new int[m];`Выделял вот так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Освобождать - грубо говоря, в порядке, обратном выделению.

**Если** вы выделяли как

```
a = new int*[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    a[i] = new int[M];
```

то и удалять нужно как

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    delete[] a[i];
delete[] a;
```

Просто тот же двумерный массив можно выделить и одним куском в памяти, тогда одним и удалять...

Comment: Не подскажете,в таком случае,как выделить одним куском и как соответственно её удалять

Comment: Это экзотика :) выделяете память для n*m элементов - `new int[n*m]`, а потом обращаетесь к (i,j)-му элементу как `a[i*m+j]`.